# Docker daemon crashes on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

So, I'm updating a cloudformation template so that it uses the Amazon Linux 2 AMI optimized for ECS [amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20190709-x86_64-ebs (ami-0fac5486e4cff37f4)]. Previously I was using ami-00129b193dc81bc31 which is an Amazon Linux 1 container.

I initially found that simply changing out the AMI meant the EC2 instances no longer joined my ECS cluster. After a lot of digging (ensuring permissions, subnet, VPC, IAM were all right) I found that the docker daemon was crashing. The reason was traceable to what I was doing with the user data. I'll paste it below:

```
        "UserData": { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"==BOUNDARY==\"\n",
          "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
          "--==BOUNDARY==\n",
          "Content-Type: text/cloud-boothook; charset=\"us-ascii\"\n",
          "#!/bin/bash\n",
          "# Set Docker daemon options\n",
          "cloud-init-per once docker_debug echo 'OPTIONS=\"${OPTIONS} --storage-opt dm.basesize=10G\"' >> /etc/sysconfig/docker\n",
          "--==BOUNDARY==\n",
          "Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset=\"us-ascii\"\n",
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
          "echo \"ECS_CLUSTER=",
          { "Ref" : "NovaProductionEcsCluster"},
          "\" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
          "sudo mkdir /efs\n",
          "sudo mkdir /efs/nova_files\n",
          "sudo useradd -u 33 www-data\n",
          "sudo chown -R www-data /efs/nova_files/\n",
          "printf \"\nfunction novarun {\n docker exec -ti \\\"\\$(docker ps -qf name=ApacheTask)\\\" \\\"\\$([ \\$# -ne 1 ] && echo \\\"bash\\\" || echo \\\"\\$1\\\")\\\" \n}\n\" >> /home/ec2-user/.bashrc\n",
          "--==BOUNDARY==--"
        ]]}}
      }
```

Basically, this combines this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html) with this (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/increase-default-ecs-docker-limit/) to increase the disk space available to the docker container. This works perfectly with the old AMI, but the new AMI gives me `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` when I run `docker ps -a`.

If I run `sudo journalctl -u docker` to get the error `Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay2: unknown option dm.basesize`.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong with this approach? Is there a way to fix this flag with ECS, or a different way to enlarge the amount of disk space available to the docker image?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just remove that Docker configuration line altogether; your (newer) Docker daemon can use all available space in whatever partition is mounted on `/var/lib/docker`.

There are several different systems ([storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/)) that Docker can use to store image and container data.  Initially Docker used [devicemapper](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) – the "dm" in your option – which didn't require special Linux kernel support, but did have a fixed-size storage allocation for all Docker content.  (Devicemapper was also slow and a little buggy; the better ways to use it involved giving it a dedicated disk partition, not just a file.)  Most newer Docker installations use [overlay2](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/), which does require special kernel support, but now that's also fairly mainstream, and overlay2 avoids most of the problems of devicemapper.

In short:

1. Your newer AMI has a newer Docker and a newer kernel.
2. Your newer Docker uses a different storage backend (`overlay2`).
3. The `dm.*` options go with a different storage backend, hence your error message.
4. You don't actually need special options any more, because one of the ways `overlay2` is better than `devicemapper` is that it can natively use all of the host system disk without configuration.

Comment: Thank you! I really hoped it was something like this. It's great when the breaking update removes what seemed like unnecessary complexity before. I needed to reconfigure block storage to change how the EBS volume mounts, but I can confirm this works.